# You must either be running with node (package.json)... Error while creating new app on rails

Tags: node.js, ruby-on-rails, tzinfo

```
TZInfo::DataSourceNotFound: tzinfo-data is not present. Please add gem 'tzinfo-data' to your Gemfile and run bundle install
C:/railsfriends/friends/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>'

Caused by:
TZInfo::DataSources::ZoneinfoDirectoryNotFound: None of the paths included in TZInfo::DataSources::ZoneinfoDataSource.search_path are valid zoneinfo directories.
C:/railsfriends/friends/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => app:template => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
       rails  turbo:install stimulus:install
# You must either be running with node (package.json) or importmap-rails (config/importmap.rb) to use this gem.
```

## You must either be running with node (package.json) or importmap-rails (config/importmap.rb) to use this gem.

To solve this,
Stay in the same directory do nothing, then type this specific command

```
$ gem install tzinfo-data
```

to install `tzinfo-data`

Answer (score 0):

**In 8 Simple Steps**

1. Go to file explorer and open the app_name folder you just tried to create.
2. open the file named **Gemfile** in any notepad
3. Find **gem "tzinfo-data", platforms: %i[ mingw mswin x64_mingw jruby ]** in the text and make sure it is not commented, if so uncomment the line of the code.
4. Now if you see gem "tzinfo-data", platforms: %i[ mingw mswin x64_mingw jruby ],  **remove the rest** of this line after gem "tzinfo-data" now you should see just **gem "tzinfo-data"**.
5. Save the file. You are now good to go on your cmd again.
6. **In the cmd** run: **cd app_name** to open the directory of the app you tried to create.
7. Now run: **bundle install**
8. After that, you can run: **rails importmap:install** again or recreate your app entirely.

Thank you, have a nice day